# Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I am using homestead and I continue to get FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: I've done  composer require illuminate/html and composer update. No luck. Here is what I have in the Provider and Aliases

app.php

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,


    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],


'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade\Form::class,
    'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade\Html::class,

],
```

];

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload -o` or `composer update`?

Comment: Yes I did... No luck with that.

Comment: can you post your composer.json file? Is this on a local server or remote?

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.3",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
    }
}

Comment: using homestead with virtual box local

Comment: `{
    "require": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.3",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5 don't use `illuminate/html` anymore. If you want this functionality you should use `laravelcollective/html`.

In your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Run `composer update`

In `app.php` in the `providers` array:

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

And, if you want or need them, in the `aliases` array:

```
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

[Laravel Collective Docs](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

Comment: Done exactly what was said... Thing is though that the convention or syntax that is in app.php is Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class, but they dont give a class in the documentation. Here is the error I am still getting when using collective: Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

and when i take out the string i get 
Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' in /home/vagrant/Code/learning-laravel-5/config/app.php on line 139

Comment: Use `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` (if you want the same syntax). If you are getting the same error all the time, take a look in your vendor folder to see if the dependency actually was installed.

Comment: I've finally gotten it. Thanks for your help!